# how to terminate running scanner command forcefully in java

Tags: java, multithreading, serversocket

I have two different classes Client.java and Server.java. Client.java has two threads one is taking input from the user using scanner class and send data to the server and one thread read from server and prints on the screen. I want to terminate running user input command if the server sends specific keyword like "shutdown".
Here is the Client code

```
package client;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DirClient extends Thread {
Socket client;
DataOutputStream out;
Scanner input;
boolean clientState = true;

DirClient(String serverName, int port) {
    try {
        client = new Socket(serverName, port);
        out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("Connected to : " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

void close() {
    clientState = false;
    input.close();
    try {
        client.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

void sendToServer() {
    String operation;
    try {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);

        ReadFromServer objRFS = new ReadFromServer(client, this);
        objRFS.start(); // start thread to read data from server
        while (clientState) { // loop to read user input and send to server
            operation = input.nextLine();
            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                break; // if operation is exit then stop recieving user
                        // input
            }
            out.writeUTF(operation);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        close();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String serverName = args[0];
    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    DirClient objDirClient = new DirClient(serverName, port);
    objDirClient.sendToServer();
}
```

}

// class to that communicate with server to get server response

```
class ReadFromServer extends Thread {

Socket client = null;
DataInputStream in = null;
DirClient objDirClient;

ReadFromServer(Socket client, DirClient dirClient) {

    try {
        this.client = client;
        objDirClient = dirClient;
        in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public void run() {
    String response;

    try {
        while (true) {
            response = in.readUTF();

            if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("shutdown")) {
                objDirClient.close();
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Response :\n" + response);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

I have called the close function from the main thread if client reads shutdown key word from the server.As control of main thread is at input from user so this does not terminate untill user enter something.

Comment: 'I want to terminate running user input command if the server sends specific keyword like "shutdown" ' - but you compare the operation to "exit"... :)

Comment: check the code in run block. and a client can manually exit.

Comment: Check the code in: `operation.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")`

Comment: If you close the underlying stream, the scanner should throw an exception. http://www.hastebin.com/ogobapaxes.avrasm

Comment: @alfasin .. that's the other funcationality.

Comment: make sure you trim spaces/newlines that might wrap the text.